# ionic 2 - watch fail

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 framework on ubuntu with node v6.9.4 and npm 3.10.10, and after the last upgrade i've gotting the error when i run "ionic serve":

```
    [11:46:06]  ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0 
    [11:46:06]  watch started ... 
    [11:46:06]  build dev started ... 
    [11:46:06]  clean started ... 
    [11:46:06]  clean finished in 59 ms 
    [11:46:06]  copy started ... 
    [11:46:06]  transpile started ... 
    [11:46:57]  transpile finished in 50.84 s 
    [11:46:57]  webpack started ... 
    [11:47:33]  copy finished in 87.03 s 
    [11:48:16]  webpack finished in 78.91 s 
    [11:48:16]  sass started ... 
    [11:48:27]  sass finished in 11.71 s 
    [11:48:27]  build dev finished in 141.78 s 
    [11:48:30]  watch failed: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file 
                referenced does not exist: /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/assets/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/index.html, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/manifest.json, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/service-worker.js, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js 
    [11:48:30]  ionic-app-script task: "watch" 
    [11:48:30]  Error: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file referenced 
                does not exist: /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/assets/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/index.html, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/manifest.json, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/src/service-worker.js, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js, 
                /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js 

    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
    npm ERR! node v6.9.4
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! SmartTrip@ watch: `ionic-app-scripts watch`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the SmartTrip@ watch script 'ionic-app-scripts watch'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the SmartTrip package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts watch
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs SmartTrip
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls SmartTrip
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/te/PhpstormProjects/smarTrip-ionic/npm-debug.log
    node--v(node:4154) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: channel closed
```

I already tried to remove the folder node_modules and run npm install again, force the npm cache clean, install the latest version of node.js, but didnt success...

Can anyone please help me?
Tks!

Comment: Did you update ionic & cordova? see what version, you are using?

Comment: Might be obvious but still want to check, do you have a folder `assets` within your `src`?

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes, the assets folder is inside the src

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

> "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0"

to the package.json

Answer (score 1):

i finally sloved my problem.

Steps than i do to slove:

1. remove node_modules folder
2. edit my package.json like as:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
```

3. run

   ```
   sudo npm install --no-optional
   ```

Thanks!